# Some hyperlinks in list aren't clickable

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, html-lists

I am new to html so please don't mind the terrible coding..

I've created a list of links on my page in wordpress, but for some reason the first few aren't clickable. They seem to be fine here, but on my page they suddenly stop working

Here's the part of my HTML having issues:

```css
.parent {
  text-align: left;
}
.parent > ul {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" style="text-align: left; margin-left:0 auto; margin-right:0 auto; position: relative; top: +0px; right: 10px;">
<ul style= "font-size: 20px;">Public Open Sessions:
 <li style="font-size: 16px;"><a href="http://shopkts.com/collections/training/products/3-day-uem-public-open-session-april-11" target="_blank" !important>April 11-13, Mississauga, Canada</a></li> 
 <li style="font-size: 16px;"><a href="http://shopkts.com/collections/training/products/3-day-uem-public-open-session-april-18" target="_blank">April 18-20, Atlanta, USA</a></li>
 <li style="font-size: 16px;"><a href="http://shopkts.com/collections/training/products/3-day-uem-public-open-session-april-25" target="_blank">April 25-27, Calgary, Canada</a></li>
 <li style="font-size: 16px;"><a href="http://shopkts.com/collections/training/products/3-day-uem-public-open-session-may-2" target="_blank">May 2-4, Vancouver, Canada</a></li>
 <li style="font-size: 16px;"><a href="http://shopkts.com/collections/training/products/3-day-uem-public-open-session-may-9" target="_blank">May 9-11, Philadelphia, USA</a></li>
 <li style="font-size: 16px;"><a href="http://shopkts.com/collections/training/products/3-day-uem-public-open-session-may-16" target="_blank">May 16-18, Washington, DC, USA</a></li>
 <li = style="font-size: 16px;"><a href="http://shopkts.com/collections/training/products/3-day-uem-public-open-session-may-23" target="_blank">May 23-25, Dallas, USA</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

What's strange is the the first 3 links won't work, while the next 4 do. But if I move it to another part of the page, it suddenly works. Is it due to something else on the page?

Here is the full html incase it's needed:

```css
.parent {
  text-align: left;
}
.parent > ul {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p style="text-align: center; font-size: 40px; color: black"> BlackBerry Open Sessions</p>
<p style="text-align: left;"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1950" src="http://www.ktsglobal.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/ps-1-e1478718264230.png" alt="ps" width="1766" height="569" /></p>
&nbsp;
<p style="text-align: left; line-height:2px">Our public open sessions consists of instructor-led training and hands-on virtual labs. Participants will learn to Plan, Deploy and Manage BlackBerry UEM or BES12</p>
<p style="text-align: left; line-height:2px">with one of our certified instructors. Make sure to check back regularily to see our updated list of events.</p>

<hr />
<p style="text-align: center; font-size: 24px;"><img class="wp-image-1922 alignleft" src="http://www.ktsglobal.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/shutterstock_196196186-e1478532776565.jpg" alt="shutterstock_196196186" width="505" height="346" /> Upcoming Public / Virtual Events:</p>
<p style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px;"></p>
<div class="parent" style="text-align: left; margin-left:0 auto; margin-right:0 auto; position: relative; top: +0px; right: 10px;">
<ul style= "font-size: 20px;">Public Open Sessions:
 <li style="font-size: 16px;"><a href="http://shopkts.com/collections/training/products/3-day-uem-public-open-session-april-11" target="_blank" !important>April 11-13, Mississauga, Canada</a></li> 
 <li style="font-size: 16px;"><a href="http://shopkts.com/collections/training/products/3-day-uem-public-open-session-april-18" target="_blank">April 18-20, Atlanta, USA</a></li>
 <li style="font-size: 16px;"><a href="http://shopkts.com/collections/training/products/3-day-uem-public-open-session-april-25" target="_blank">April 25-27, Calgary, Canada</a></li>
 <li style="font-size: 16px;"><a href="http://shopkts.com/collections/training/products/3-day-uem-public-open-session-may-2" target="_blank">May 2-4, Vancouver, Canada</a></li>
 <li style="font-size: 16px;"><a href="http://shopkts.com/collections/training/products/3-day-uem-public-open-session-may-9" target="_blank">May 9-11, Philadelphia, USA</a></li>
 <li style="font-size: 16px;"><a href="http://shopkts.com/collections/training/products/3-day-uem-public-open-session-may-16" target="_blank">May 16-18, Washington, DC, USA</a></li>
 <li = style="font-size: 16px;"><a href="http://shopkts.com/collections/training/products/3-day-uem-public-open-session-may-23" target="_blank">May 23-25, Dallas, USA</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="parent" style="margin-left:0 auto; margin-right:0 auto;position: relative; top: -238px;  right: -380px;">
<ul style= "font-size: 20px;">Virtual Sessions:
 <li style="font-size: 16px;"><a href="http://shopkts.com/collections/training/products/uem-vilt-march-29-public-session" target="_blank">March 29-31</a></li>
 <li style="font-size: 16px;"><a href="http://shopkts.com/collections/training/products/uem-vilt-april-12-public-session" target="_blank">April 12-14</a></li>
 <li style="font-size: 16px;"><a href="http://shopkts.com/collections/training/products/uem-vilt-april-26-public-session" target="_blank">April 26-28</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
<p style="text-align: right; font-size: 20px; position: relative; top: +0px; right: 10px;">Click the training session you'd like to join to see more and sign up.<p/>
<hr style="position: relative; top: -30px;"/>
<img class="wp-image-1949 alignright" src="http://www.ktsglobal.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/las-vegas-signs-clouds-blue-sky-1920x1080-e1478718166731.jpg" alt="las-vegas-signs-clouds-blue-sky-1920x1080" width="486" height="392" />
<p style="text-align: center; font-size: 24px;">Coming Soon</p>
<p style="font-size: 18px;">We are planning a special  3-day BlackBerry UEM training event in Las Vegas.</p>

<p style="font-size: 18px;">The training will focus on some new and exciting features of BlackBerry UEM.</p>

<p style="font-size: 18px;">Feel free to contact our team for more information. We hope to see you there!</p>
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
<hr style="position: relative; top: 20px; width:100%;"/>

<p style="text-align: center;font-size: 20px"><a href="http://www.ktsglobal.ca/course-sign-up-form/"><strong><span style="color: #0020c2;">Contact us for more info</span></strong></a></h4></p>
```

It looks like a mess but trust me, it works on the page.

[Here's a link to the page](http://www.ktsglobal.ca/public-sessions/)

Any help would be great, thank you in advance!

Comment: It has to do with the way you're positioning the 2 lists on your page. Add `z-index: 1;` to the `.parent` div on the left (the first one for "public open sessions"). If you want a better way to position those 2 elements, you should change your post (or start a new one) to include both of those lists here in the post (don't just link to your site).

Comment: Also -- just for better practice: remove "!important" from the first link, and remove the "=" between "<li" and "style=" in the last list item.

Comment: Leon Freire seems to have fixed my problem, but thank you for the help and for your time!

Comment: @jkd_dev not sure why the extra "=" was there and the "!important" was me testing that to see if it could fix the problem.. But if you didn't mention it I probably would have forgotten to remove that stuff, so thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I found it.
Try this:

```
.parent {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Your second "parent" div is covering up your links. Your code is actually really basic, so this probably isn't the best way to solve it, but it will work for you at this point.

Comment: Like I said, I'm pretty new to this haha but yes that worked! Thank you, I apreciate the help

Comment: I know. I'm not judging! Haha... I'm just saying that are several better solutions, but as you are a beginner, this will solve it for you right now. But in the future you will see that there are more effective and clean ways to do it.

Comment: If this solved it for you, consider accepting the answer so it may help people again in the future! Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and it worked fine, even in your webpaged link above. I don't see any problem. However, I found a typo (?) in the last `<li>`

```
<li = style="font-size: 16px;">
```

It should be:

```
<li style="font-size: 16px;">
```

Comment: I can't seem to recreate the problem here, but it's been fixed now on my site. Also fixed the typo haha but thank you